# Random Permutation with fixed cycle length.

Tags: pr.probability, random-permutations

Suppose $ S_{n,N} $ be the set of $n$ elements with $N$ many cycles where $N$ is proportional to $n$. $U_{n,N}$ is an element picked randomly from this. It is known that the length of any cycle cannot be too large. What if we restrict the cycle lengths to be odd and then pick uniformly from this? Should it be also be that there are no cycles with huge length w.h.p?

I can prove this is the case if cycle lengths are all even. Is there any known reference for this?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it.  Is $S$ a "set of $n$ elements" as you say, or a set of permutations of $n$ elements?  And should "with $N$ many cycles" be "with $N$ cycles"?

Comment: @gmath: It would also be nice to have the references of the two results you mentioned.

Comment: Do you mean that fixing the constant of proportionality between $n$ and $N$ and letting $n$ grow, there is a size $C$ so that with probability approaching $1$ the longest cycle is shorter than $C$ (or  $C \log{n}$ or something like that?) Be more specific please.

Comment: Although I don't see all of the details, the result for odd cycles should follow from the result for even cycles by combining pairs of cycles of odd length into cycles of even length. 

Comment: @Brendan: Yes you are right. $S_{n,N}$ is the set of permutations of a set of $n$ elements with $N$ cycles. Sorry for being sloppy.



Comment: @John Jiang: Here is the result with no restriction on cycle lengths: http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/dma.2003.13.issue-5/156939203322694781/156939203322694781.xml

For the even lengths here is an argument: Note we want probability of an event depending only on the cycle type. I consider a map from $S_{n/2,N}$ to "$S_{n,N}$ with even cycle lengths"  which sends a cycle type (k_1,...k_N) to (2k_1, ... 2k_n). The map is measure preserving (one can check) if we consider uniform measure on the range. Hence the result follows from the results about uniform measure on $S_{n,N}$.

Comment: @Aaron: I want to show after fixing the proportionality constant that for large enough $n$ the probability that the largest cycle is greater than $C$ goes to zero uniformly in $n$.

Comment: @Douglas: I was thinking in the same lines but couldnt find a proof. Could you be more specific? How are the measures same? thanks.

Comment: Do you know the asymptotic size of $S_{n,N}$?  I'm pretty sure that will provide a good estimate for what you ask.

Comment: @Brendan: Yes those are exactly what is known as stirling numbers of the first kind but I couldn't find anything for odd length cycles. Finding the asymptotics for odd length cycle is possible from whats known but its very very complicated (at least via the method I thought). I am trying to see of there is a softer argument. 

Comment: @gmath: Sorry, I meant for odd cycles. It shouldn't be too hard since the generating function is simple. I think $\sum Q_{n,N} x^n y^N/n! = ((1+x)/(1-x))^{y/2}$ where $Q_{n,N}$ is the number of permutations with $N$ odd cycles.